# Can AL druids choose what magical shields are made from when found, if its description doesn't say?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, armor, dnd-adventurers-league, shield

In Adventurers League is it possible for a player to choose the type of material of shields that is found during a session ? In particular when the object description does not state its material type.

This would be useful for druids.

- The aim of this question is just to avoid having my druid roll for an object that the druid would later discover he cannot use; there is a lack of time to get information when the time to roll comes

Comment: Related: [Can a breastplate be crafted with non-metal materials in Adventurers League?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119053/41726)

Comment: I've tried to answer your problem, but as I was writing the answer, I noticed it might help if you could specify your situation, if it is a real problem that happened. Did you get a specific item and you don't know if you can use it? That is, if you can, detail your problem more, currently it is kinda broad and unclear, specially since most items **will** state its material type, directly or not.

Comment: I moved your last comment into your question to clear up The Problem You Are Trying To Solve.

Comment: @Iuiuiuiu Can you exemplify a scenario where it might happen (it would also help if it's from an actual official adventure)? I'm really unsure about it. The only situation I can think of is having a Magical Shield being rolled from a random table. Every other situation seems to specify if you can or not use the item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer might not answer your question, but it seems to answer the intent behind it.

Let us consider two scenarios. The first is that the item is a +X item. The second is that it is a specific magic item. By the end let's consider the Shields, which are... a very special case.

## +1/+2/+3 items

It depends on the original item. Pages 144 and 145 from PHB state which armor has metal on it or not. [This answer lists them](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/119054/43856). If you get a Breasplate +1, you can't use it.

## Specific items

Some of them are listed as "Armor (Plate)" or "Armor (Chain Mail)" - these are already implied having metal, so you can't use them.

If nothing indicates they are made of metal, neither in their type (e.g. (Chain Mail) as mentioned above) or in their description, they simply aren't, so you can use them. It's a similar concept to Spells do what they say. If the item doesn't state it is made of metal, it is not.

This is different from saying you can choose the material it is made of. It might be wood, wool or simply a magical thread that you don't even know what it is. What you know is: It's not made of metal, because it doesn't say it is made of metal, thus you can use it.

## Shields

This one is delicate. The adventure giving you the loot should specify what kind of shield it is (Wood or Metal). If it doesn't, since both have the same AC, it doesn't make much sense to assume it is a metal shield just so druids can't use it.

---

About the problem you mentioned:

> The aim of this question is just to avoid having my druid roll for an object that the druid would later discover he cannot use; there is a lack of time to get information when the time to roll comes

From my experience, agreed by [Duck's comment<sup>1</sup>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122837/can-al-druids-choose-what-magic-shields-armor-are-made-from-when-found-if-its-d/122869#comment302367_122869) , this scenario is very unlikely and probably simply won't happen. Either it will be specified by the item itself or by the adventure. If the DM doesn't say anything about it, ask him before rolling. "Is this item made of metal?". In AL, rewards are distributed at the **end of a play session**, as mentioned in the [AL DM guide](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/AL_DMG_YP.pdf), page 5. So you should have time to search the DMG and check if the magic item is specified as a plate (for example, Armor of Vulnerability is) or what.

Also, if the item can't be used by you and you show interest in it, it's very likely that other players or the DM will warn you about it, mainly if they are experienced, and you will then (hopefully) change your decision.

---

<sup>1</sup>  [I can't speak to every AL adventure but all the equipment that has dropped in the adventures I have done with my druid have specified material type. Which is frustrating since I use shields and have had to pass up 3 magic ones already](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122837/can-al-druids-choose-what-magical-shields-are-made-from-when-found-if-its-descr/122869?noredirect=1#comment302367_122869) (@Duck)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm currently asking for more details from the OP. IMO right now he's overthinking things - the scenario he's worried about seems very unlikely or even impossible. My only experience that ""helps"" with this question is: this scenario never happened.

Comment: @HellSaint I think you are right. I can't speak to every AL adventure but all the equipment that has dropped in the adventures I have done with my druid have specified material type. Which is frustrating since I use shields and have had to pass up 3 magic ones already.

Comment: This answer was written for the [Revision 7](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/122837/7) of the question. I don't intend to edit it because the answer still takes into account the current version and the leftovers for general Armor might still help people in doubt, AL or not, if their druids can use a magical armor or not.

Comment: Aye, good effort.  I tossed in Duck's comment as a footnote since comments eventually go away.